# paste0 multiple lists of different lengths without looping

Tags: r

I am paste0'ing a bunch of variables into a definitive url list

```
id <- 1:10
animal <- c("dog", "cat", "fish")
base <- "www.google.com/"

urls <- paste0(base, "id=", id, "search=", animal)
```

The output looks like:

```
 [1] "www.google.com/id=1search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=2search=cat"  "www.google.com/id=3search=fish"
 [4] "www.google.com/id=4search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=5search=cat"  "www.google.com/id=6search=fish"
 [7] "www.google.com/id=7search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=8search=cat"  "www.google.com/id=9search=fish"
[10] "www.google.com/id=10search=dog"
```

But I actually want the `ids` and `animals` to be repeated in sequence like:

```
 [1] "www.google.com/id=1search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=2search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=3search=dog"
 [4] "www.google.com/id=4search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=5search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=6search=dog"
 [7] "www.google.com/id=7search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=8search=dog"  "www.google.com/id=9search=dog"
[10] "www.google.com/id=10search=dog" "www.google.com/id=1search=cat"   ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the code by including `rep` in `paste0` or `sprintf`

```
 sprintf('%sid=%dsearch=%s', base, id, rep(animal,each=length(id)))
```

Or

```
 paste0(base, 'id=',id, 'search=', rep(animal,each=length(id)))
```

Or as @MrFlick suggested, we can use `expand.grid` to get all the combinations between 'animal' and 'id'

```
  with(expand.grid(a=animal, i=id), paste0(base, "id=", i, "search=", a))
```

Comment: That's a good use of vector recycling. You can also be more explicit with `exapand.grid`: `with(expand.grid(a=animal, i=id), paste0(base, "id=", i, "search=", a))`